# I can't change a class background-color on click with this code. Why?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function checker() {
       if ($(".check-box-label").css("background-color") === "none"){
           $(".check-box-label").css("background-color", "#1F7566")
       }else{
           $(".check-box-label").css("background-color", "none")
       }
    };
});

$(".check-box-label").on("click", checker);
```

With this code, the .check-box-label background-color were suposed to alternate colors on click depending on the actual background-color value, why isn't it working? Thanks

Comment: Why is `$(".check-box-label").on("click", checker);` outside of your doc.ready call? Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Scope issue with the method being defined in the ready callback.

Comment: And side note; this logic would be much cleaner with toggling classes.  Though now that I look closer, both the if and the else are applying the same background color hex codes...

Comment: You're rigth, now that i've had included `$(".check-box-label").on("click", checker);` inside the doc.ready, it is partialy working, but now only the `else` block is working. Like, i click once, and the `background-color` changes, but when i click again, it doesn't change.

Comment: @Megalypse that might be partly because both the clauses of your `if` statement set the background to the same colour...

Comment: @Megalypse ok now that's better. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58880724/5947043) below for why that doesn't work.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

couple of issues,

1.) `.css("backgroundColor")` returns rgb, not hex, so I added a common method used to convert to hex

2.) setting background-color to none, will not work. You need to use either "transparent" or "initial" instead

```js
function rgb2hex(rgb) {
     if (  rgb.search("rgb") == -1 ) {
          return rgb;
     } else {
          rgb = rgb.match(/^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(\d+))?\)$/);
          function hex(x) {
               return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
          }
          return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]); 
     }
}

function checker() {
   var targetColor = "#1f7566";
   var color = $(".check-box-label").css("backgroundColor");
   console.log(rgb2hex(color), rgb2hex(color) != targetColor)
   if (rgb2hex(color) != targetColor){
       $(".check-box-label").css("background-color", targetColor)
   }else{
       $(".check-box-label").css("background-color", "initial")
   }
};

$(".check-box-label").on("click", checker);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="check-box-label">
things
</label>
```

Comment: For some reason this code doesn't work when clicking on labels, but when clicking on divs, it's completely functional

Comment: I was able to make the html above a `<label>` and it still works.. Must be your implementation, maybe click is being caught and stopped?